# IntelliJ IDEA: How to run gradle application plugin run task with --args

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a java main program in my gradle project which I can run via command line using the gradle application plugin run task with --args param new since gradle 4.9 as follows:

```
gradle  run --args="-ahttp://foo.com/bar -dmydeviceid"
```

I would like to create a Run Configuration for the same in IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.1.

- I specify Task field in Run/Debug Configuration dilog as `run`.
- I specify Arguments field as --args="-ahttp://foo.com/bar -dmydeviceid"

When I run this run config I get the error:

```
11:58:31 AM: Executing task 'run --args="-ahttp://foo.com/bar -dmydeviceid"'...

Unknown command-line option '--args'.
```

How can I make this work via run config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create a new Run Config as follows for the main program:

1. Open Run/Debug Configurations dialog vie Edit Configuration choice in pulldown left of Run button
2. Expand Defaults menu and select Application
3. Click + to create an Application run config
4. Enter your Main class
5. Enter program arguments. For my example above it was: `-ahttp://foo.com/bar -dmydeviceid`
6. Enter module in "Use classpath module". It is likely the one with suffix "_main"
7. Click OK
8. Now click run or debug button